# German license with 4 signs

Tags: license-plates

I came across this German license plate of which I really don't know where it comes from. It has 4 signs, consisting of 3 letters and 1 number. See picture beneath:

[image: German license]

I don't have to know from what region it comes (privacy for the car owner) but really want to know if this is just a common license plate or a special one. I'm used to 6 symbols on a (European) license plate, 4 seems really uncommon for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not maintenance or repair...

Comment: A single character in the middle and a single digit at the end is rare, but possible. There is no special meaning, in fact, one can choose this part. More interesting is that OP means Opladen. Once a city on its own, it is part of Leverkusen since 1975. So, OP is not assigned any more, today they get LEV.  (I'm living almost next to Opladen)

Comment: @sweber so I was correct for the important part then...

Comment: Maybe a Diplomat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two letters are the designation of a particular town or licensing area, after that I can’t remember but should be easy enough to google...

So see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_Germany